# How to use v-for and source binding together in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-cli

I want to render my cards from an array, and bind their names as source with v-bind:src in Vue.js

I came here so far, binding looks cool in console, but I can't see images still here my code below

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div v-for="image in images" :key="image.id" class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2"><img class="card" :src="'../assets/' + image + '.jpg'" alt=""></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                images: [
                    "card-1",
                    "card-2",
                    "card-3",
                    "card-4",
                    "card-5",
                    "card-6"
                ],
            };
        }
    };
</script>
```

Here playground:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-udd08

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `require` to show image from dynamic path 
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-hcrjb

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. I'm just asking for learn, why we need to use require? For using Vue-CLI ?